# Show that there is no polynomial $f \in (\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})$ satisfying f(1)=1 and f(11)=17

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

As stated in the title. This is part of a homework assignment.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?  Have you tried any approaches so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is such an $f$, let $g(x)=f(x+1) -x-1$ (this will still be some polynomial). The given information about $f$ translates into $g(0)= 0$ and $g(10) = 6$. Can you see why no such $g$ can exist?